# Is the dollar sign somehow related to C++ pointers?

Tags: php, c++

Today I saw a post on php.net, that I'm quoting here:

```
$Bar = "a";
$Foo = "Bar";
$World = "Foo";
$Hello = "World";
$a = "Hello";

$a; //Returns Hello
$$a; //Returns World
$$$a; //Returns Foo
$$$$a; //Returns Bar
$$$$$a; //Returns a

$$$$$$a; //Returns Hello
$$$$$$$a; //Returns World
```

Since PHP inherits its syntax from C++, doesn't the dollar sign remind you of pointers?

```
string bar = "a";
string *foo = &bar;
string **world = &foo;
string ***hello = &world;
string ****a = &hello;
```

Just like pointers, when you define `$a = 'var'` and `$var = 'test'` and then you do `$$a` you are using the value of `$a` to point to `$var` which is kinda what happens with C++ pointers just with strings instead of memory addresses.

So can the dollar sign in PHP be related to C++ pointers?

Comment: Just for curiosity, why the down vote?

Comment: was not me, but this seems a bit off topic and "chatty" for S.O

Comment: @Dagon, it's a naive question like any other. Ok maybe unusual but still a question that CAN be answered.

Comment: @JeffPigarelli "Since PHP derives from C++..."  What, like English derives from German?  Tell me all about how English verbs differ for each of the cases: Nominative, Accusative, Dative, Genitive.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Since PHP derives from C++...

***Stop.*** This line of thinking will get you nothing but pain and suffering. [Perl, LPC, Lua, Pike, Ada 95, Java, PHP, D, C99, C#, and Falcon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B) are all derived from C++ as well, for some definition of "derived", and I can guarantee you they act nothing like C++ and are certainly not used like C++ either. The similarities are superficial in nature,  and their semantics are totally different.

---

In the case you provided above, it's more similar to languages like Javascript in the sense that you can resolve and dereference a variable name *given only a string*. In C++ knowing just the name of the variable doesn't allow you to dereference the variable. What you need is its memory address (hence the `&` operator). That's the key difference.

I think the most salient point of misunderstanding here is this part of your question:

> Just like pointers, when you define $a = 'var' and $var = 'test' and
> then you do $$a you are using the R-value of $a to point to $var which
> is kinda what happens with C++ pointers.

This isn't explanation doesn't capture the entire picture with regards to pointers. I assume you're talking about things like these:

PHP:

```
$var = 'test' 
$a = 'var'
//$$a == 'test'
```

C++:

```
std::string var = "test";
std::string* a = &var;
// *a == "test";
```

The big difference between the two is that C++'s `a` contains a *memory address* for the `var` variable, not a string containing the name of the variable `var`.

It's more like [reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_science)) than anything else, which C++ certainly does not have as standard, and thus cannot just simply dereference a variable given only a string name.

From [the PHP documentation for variable variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php):

> Sometimes it is convenient to be able to have variable variable names.
> That is, **a variable name which can be set and used dynamically.** [emphasis mine]

If C++ had that kind of functionality, it would be more like this:

```
std::string Bar = "a"; 
std::string Foo = "Bar"; 
std::string World = "Foo"; 
std::string Hello = "World"; 
std::string a = "Hello"; 

// Hypothetical function dyn_deref_str that gets the string value
// held by a variable given only its name.
a; //Returns "Hello"
dyn_deref_str(a); //Returns "World" 
dyn_deref_str(dyn_deref_str(a)); //Returns "Foo" 
dyn_deref_str(dyn_deref_str(dyn_deref_str(a))); //Returns "Bar" 
dyn_deref_str(dyn_deref_str(dyn_deref_str(dyn_deref_str(a)))); //Returns "a"
```

This is very different from simple pointer dereferencing, as pointers do not hold strings, they hold memory addresses. Even though you [shouldn't be using pointers in your code anyway](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/6101039/Modern%20C%2B%2B.pdf) except in very specific circumstances.

Comment: In fact, this can easily be modelled with a `std::(unordered_)map`. :)

Answer (score 5):

This has nothing to do with pointers. It's much rather an instance of **reflection**, by which a piece of string becomes code. C++ does not have such kind of reflection.

Reflection is possible in PHP: The interpreter is running while the program executes, and thus it is possible to feed a string back into the interpreter as a piece of code.

*Java* has a someone related mechanism by which you can specify the name of a class as a string at runtime, and the Java VM can then *load* that class at runtime and instantiate an object of its type. Java executes in some manner of managed context, while C++ programs generally do not: When a C++ program is compiled, there's no trace of "C++" left, and it's just machine code*.

<sub>*) Pedant’s footnote: Unless of course you happen to be compiling a C++ compiler.</sub>

Comment: Pedantry alert: Being a compiled language doesn't prohibit reflection.

Comment: You have to admit that variable variables behave like pointers someway. Isn't it?

Comment: @JeffPigarelli: Nope; I neither have to admit that, nor is it the case. Variable variables are much more like `eval`.

Comment: I have to disagree with the distinction you're trying to make.  It is not the fact that Java runs in a JVM that enables reflection.  In fact, Java can be compiled to native machine code, and it still "works".

Comment: Nothing prevents a C++ compiler from producing more than machine code and preserving some of the C++. In fact, this already happens with `std::typeinfo` instances.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Yet there is no mechanism by which you can read a typeinfo-like datum at runtime and instantiate an object of that type, nor would such a construction make sense in the object model of C++.

Comment: Look, of course C++ is whatnot complete and all, and you could *write* an entire system which behaves in whichever way you want, including something that consumes C++ code and has reflection. The point is that it's not natively part of C++ and not well fitted to its idioms.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Yes, precisely.  The point is that the language wasn't designed as such, not that it is compiled.

Comment: @KerrekSB but that is not at all related to being compiled or not. It's just that C++ doesn't require any useful information to be kept after compilation. But if the information is retained (and in practice, some of it is), it can be used. Take for example the hypothetical `deref` function mentioned in In silico's answer: it is actually quite similar to POSIX's `dlsym`.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: But `dlsym` is hardly any reflection: You need to *know* the function signature out-of-band to make use of the function. You can *not* discover the correct signature from the library at runtime and create an appropriately typed function pointer.

Comment: @KerrekSB: You seem to now be arguing that C++ doesn't have (very much) reflection. But nobody disagrees on that point. Their disagreement is that you seem to be claiming the previous fact is so *because C++ is a native-compiled language*, which I'll jump on the bandwagon and say that's false too. C++ only happens to have bad reflection support by design, not by necessity.

Comment: @GManNickG: Alright, I removed the offending passage.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Sounds good to me. This means you now have one Compel-GMan-To-Change-His-Post card.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it does relate to pointers. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Variable variables don't address memory adresses, but resolve names in the structure used to hold php variables.

Answer (score 0):

Pointers contain nothing but adresses, here you are using a variable for the "name" of another variable you want to access..